# Rendering image in BandedGridColumn from MySQL Blob field

Tags: c#, mysql, devexpress

I have a number of images stored in a `Blob` type field inside a MySQL InnoDB database  along with other information pertaining to those images stored in another fields.

As you know the [Banded Grid View](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument3467) distributed in DevExpress version 11.2, with the help of [Banded Grid Columns](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraGridViewsBandedGridBandedGridColumntopic), is capable of rendering several types of data, most notably images.

So far I'm able to create every control and load any kind of data required, including the images, using the common `MySqlDataReader` and `DataSet` approach, through the [Grid Control](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraGridGridControltopic) `DataSource` property, that owns the `BandedGridView`.

However as you know, when you load a Blob field from MySQL you are returned a byte array with the content of the file, in this case the image in question.

I was hoping DevExpress would recognize the binary data and realize it was a image file, and automatically render the image in all the rows under the Column assigned to handle the database `Image` field, however it did not and now that I think of it, it was probably far fetched hope.

Instead of rendering the image, each row of the column shows a simple string output referencing what type of object the field contains. In this case since its a binary representation of a file, it outputs `System.Byte[]`.

I've search the DevExpress documentation and generally on the web, nothing clear was found that could solve my problem. There is a example of my desired result packed along with DevExpress, the solution named "GridMainDemo" under the WinForms -> XtraGrid section. Once your running the demo, change into Alternate Views and into Banded Grid View, then just click on any row under the picture column, and you will see a clear example of my desired result.

Of course I've looked into the source of that demo, however I cannot say that clarification and explanation was a clear aim of the DevExpress team that built such demo, and unfortunately I didn't had much time to look at it deeply. However from what I've seen this demo differs from the point that the images are stored locally as files, and already properly reference in some sort of repository, which doesn't help much with my problem.

To finish my question, sorry for the long reading, just wanted to give a clear idea of what my aim is, what stands in the way, and how all things are set in order to find a way to reach my aim.

Now to cut a long story short. A simple example of how to load a image from a MySQL Blob field into a column in a Banded Grid View and have it rendered after load or when the user clicks the field cell, would be ideal and with it I would be able to understand and do the necessary code so that my View also renders my images.

My biggest thanks with this, really.

> Note: Unfortunately, using local or even remote stored files is not
>   a option. The images must be kept within the confinements of the
>   database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't so hard after all, and seems hope was well place and DevExpress did most of the work.

So, to help those who have a similar question, here is what you have to do, so you can have a certain column showing a image stored in a Blob type field.

> *Assuming you already loaded the data to your grid and it's being displayed correctly with the exception of the image of course.*

**First:** You must declare a `RepositoryItemImageEdit` type object, that will simply implement a `ImageEdit` type control in the cell, which when trying to edit the cell value it will show your image, the goal of this question. If your goal differs on that point simply read the note after this answer afterwards.

**Second:** You must add the previously last declared object to your `GridControl.RepositoryItems` collection property. You can easily accomplish it using the `Add` method.

**Third:** Now you must define what type of control will be used to render the data for you Image column, for that you simple reference the `BandedGridColumn.ColumnEdit` property to be equal to the object you just added before.

**Example**

```
/* Create your columns, bands etc manually or
have it done automatically after loading the data.*/
...
// Load the data from the database to your gridControl
...
// Step one
RepositoryItemImageEdit imageControl = new RepositoryItemImageEdit();
// Step two
gridControl.RepositoryItems.Add(imageControl);
// Step three
/* view is the View assigned to your grid control
where your data and columns are being shown.*/
// Assuming your database blob field is named `Image`
view.Columns["Image"].ColumnEdit = imageControl;
```

If your data was loaded correctly and your columns assigned properly to their respective fields then this should render a small icon on each cell of your Image column and once your click or focus on it, a `ImageEdit` control will be rendered and show your image.

> **Note:**
>
> There are other controls besides `ImageEdit` capable of rendering images, for those others you will have to find
>   their`RepositoryItem` based implementation.
>
> Also, your Image column must be editable, otherwise this approach won't
>   work. Bare in mind that allowing edition at the column level will not work if it is denied at the View level through the `OptionsBehavior.Editable` property.

I will mark my answer as the correct one since no one else provided any insight on how to solve my problem, however you are welcome to post any other working approaches to this problem. Thank you.